# How can I store an Array of Ints in my database, in a single field, using Code First Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What I want to do is store an Array of Ints in my database. I am Using Code First Entity Framework to create my database I can't seem to create a List or Array element in the database. The List item doesn't create a field. I gather that this is because it would need a separate table.

What is the best way to store my array in a single field here. Should I convert the array to a String, or is there an easier way?

My model contains:

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public List<int> IdArray { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can store it in one column with some delimiter and later split it but isn't it better to store all those items in separated table with id referencing to it's "owner" ?

Comment: You will regret storing these in a single row instead of splitting them out into their own table...

Comment: EF should handle this as a one-to-many relation.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate supports this, but EF doesn't.

If you need to do it the only option is to store it serialized. For example you can do:

- a `XML` column, and store it serialzed as XML
- a `char` column, and store it serialized as JSON

EF will not automatically serialize / deserialize it. You should add a property that does the serialization/deserialization for you

```
public string IdsColumn { get; set; } // Mapped to DB

[NotMapped]
public List<int> Ids
{
    get { return Deserialize(IdsColumn); }
    set { IdsColumn = Serialize(value); }
}
```

Of course you have to provide the serialization functions implementation, using `XMLSerializer` or JSON.NET, for example.

If you want this functionality implemented, look here: [EF data user voice](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions?query=collections)

For example [Richer collection support, including ordered collections and dictionaries of value types](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions?query=collections)

You can vote for it.

Answer (score 0):

Im not too sure of your situation but Most of the time this is never necessary...

Basically if you arrive at such a situation you should look at normalizing your table further. data in tables need to be "atomic". once retrieved as objects it can be in a list.